# タグ候補の表示時に名前が長いタグが見切れる

Tags: バグ, デザイン

タグ候補の表示時に、名前の長いタグが見切れています。以下の画像では、[シンタックスハイライト](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e3%82%b7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%bf%e3%83%83%e3%82%af%e3%82%b9%e3%83%8f%e3%82%a4%e3%83%a9%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88), [他言語サイトでの提案](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%e4%bb%96%e8%a8%80%e8%aa%9e%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e6%8f%90%e6%a1%88) というタグの右側にある疑問符のアイコンが見切れています。

[image: 他言語サイトでの提案というタグの右側にあるはてなマークのアイコンが見切れている]

Comment: ディスプレイ (ブラウザ) の表示サイズに依存しそうです。

Comment: @cubick さん> コメントありがとうございます。私が検証した限りでは、タグ候補が表示される箇所の横幅は一定になっているようです。

Comment: @supa こちら、私が今現在 mac の chrome で検証してみたのですが、再現していないですね。。ブラウザは何を利用されています？

Comment: @YukiInoue さん> コメントありがとうございます。ブラウザは Opera, Chrome を使用しています。こちらでは再現するので、もう少しちゃんと再現条件を調べてみようと思います。